# Leads aren't re-entering Journey, despite being updated

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, journeybuilder

I'm using the REST API to send Leads to Salesforce.

I have a Journey that reacts when new Leads get created **or updated** in Salesforce (i.e. Salesforce Data entry source).

[image]

The only entry criteria is that LeadSource *contains* 'Web'. (which also isn't working - it only lets Leads in when LeadSource is *exactly* 'Web').

I have the Journey clearly marked 're-entry anytime'.

[image]

My problem is that, when I create a Lead using Salesforce REST API, the Lead enters fine (but only if LeadSource is *exactly* 'Web'), but if I "Update" the Lead, it doesn't re-enter like I'd expect.

I've updated the Lead by changing it's LeadSource to, e.g. 'Web123', and it doesn't re-enter.

I've also created Leads that start off with a LeadSource of 'Web123', which don't enter it, then I update them to a LeadSource of 'Web', and they *still* don't enter it, even if they've never entered it.

Am I thinking about Entry events wrong?

Also, I just noticed that it says, "**Contact** Entry" - are all my Leads automatically being converted to Contacts? Are Leads never able to re-enter, and only Contacts can?

I greatly appreciate any wisdom you can share.

Comment: Hi Jamin, I don’t know the answers to all your questions, but here’s a couple of thoughts: 1. SFMC “Contacts” are any records. They can be Leads, Contacts, Person Accounts - it’s just how SFMC calls them. Any records can re-enter and nothing gets automatically converted. 2. Regarding updated leads not entering - please see this: https://sforce.co/365CcBC and see if you are able to analyze the issue further using this: https://bit.ly/2Q7i6kR 3. Regarding the contains/equals filter - I will have a look later and see if I can reproduce this

Comment: Hi @zuzannamj, thanks for the details - they helped clarify what was going on. Also, the 'Web123' *CONTAINS* issue might have been my imagination - it seems to be working fine now.

Comment: Glad it’s working!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the Update criteria using [Salesforce Data Event](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_salesforce_data_event.htm&type=5&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null), the record must meet the criteria after the update. For example, if the value already contains ‘Web’ then it needs to change to another value not containing ‘Web’ such as null then back to ‘Web’.

> When a record is updated, the rule runs only if the record meets rule
>   criteria after the update. The rule does not run when a record that
>   previously met rule criteria is updated.

Comment: Thank you very much, this solved the problem. The only other work-around would've been a huge hassle.

Comment: Hi @Jackson Chen, though this concept looks so simple, but yet tricky!... Thanks for explaining so CRISP and CLEAR, so everyone can understand this.